# Using MEF with ActiveX Controls (*.ocx) Possible?

Tags: mef, ocx, activexobject

Geneally all **MEF** examples use class libraries as "*.**dll**". Is it possible to use **ActiveX Conrols** (*.**ocx** files instead of "dll" files") from MEF directly.?

Best Wishes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. The [Managed Extensibility Framework](http://mef.codeplex.com/) is a .NET technology. It can only handle DLL files which are [.NET assemblies](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k3677y81.aspx).

OCX files are native libraries containing a COM type library. They are not .NET assemblies.

Comment: Deleted my answer as I think this one's better in the context.